# after() vs update() in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am new to python and started working with tkinter as canvas.

up to now i used .update() to update my canvas. but there is also a .after() method. could anyone explain me this function (with an example please :) ) and is there a difference between:

```
 root.after(integer,call_me)
```

and

```
while(True):
    time.sleep(integer)
    root.update()
    call_me
```

i have searched already and couldn't find a good explanation (and my .after examples wont work neither :( ).

Answer (score 4):

`update()` yields to the event loop (`mainloop`), allowing it to process pending events.

`after`, when given one or more arguments, simply places an event on the event queue with a timestamp. The event won't be processed until the given time has passed and the event loop has a chance to process it.

The important thing to know is that the event loop needs to be able to constantly respond to events. Events aren't just used for button clicks and keyboard keys, it is used to respond to requests to redraw the windows, scroll data, change borders and colors when you hover over widgets, etc.

When you call `sleep()`, the program does exactly that - it sleeps. While it is sleeping it is unable to process any events. Any sleeping will cause your GUI to stutter. The longer the sleep, the more noticeable the stutter.

Comment: so it is better to use after if i dont want a frozen screen? and update() only if i want ignore the time passing between two events?

Comment: @Steelbean: I don't quite know how to answer that. `after` and `update` do two completely different things so there's never of choice of choosing one over the other. If you want to do something periodically, use `after` to place events on the queue. In general, you should never call `update` unless there's no other way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

`root.after(integer, call_me)` is similar to

```
while(True):
    time.sleep(integer)
    root.update()
    call_me()
```

but it does it within the main loop, `integer` specifies the milliseconds rather than the seconds, and you can continue to do things after you call it, because it does it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

`after` is time wait. `update` is refresh `tkinter` tasks.
`after` is use to move objects (for example), while `refresh` allow to refresh the screen.

```
time.sleep(integer)
```

don't allow to do anything else when sleeping (blocking)!

While `after` allow `tkinter` to do other things.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all program waits for excution your function , just use:

```
def MineAfter(var):
    time.sleep(var)
    root.update()

MineAfter(2)
My_function(var1,var2)
```

if you want your function waits for some time while program continue execution use:

```
root.after(100,lambda:my_function(var1,var2))
```

or for functions without variables:

```
root.after(100,my_function)
```